# Pubsub using Topic Groups with Akka Cluster

Tags: scala, akka, publish-subscribe, akka-cluster

I'm trying to create a pubsub-style application with Akka Cluster. I'm reading [the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/distributed-pub-sub.html#Publish) about pubsub and am trying to now run their example.

My basic workflow is this:

Run the subscriber (who becomes the master/leader).
Run the publisher (who will send a string to the topic. All subscribers will receive this message).

Here's my code:

#### `Subscriber.scala`

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.cluster.pubsub.{DistributedPubSub, DistributedPubSubMediator}

class Subscriber extends Actor with ActorLogging {
  import DistributedPubSubMediator.{ Subscribe, SubscribeAck }
  val mediator = DistributedPubSub(context.system).mediator
  // subscribe to the topic named "content"
  mediator ! Subscribe("content", self)

  def receive = {
    case s: String =>
      log.info("Got {}", s)
    case SubscribeAck(Subscribe("content", None, `self`)) =>
      log.info("subscribing");
  }
}

object SubscriberMain extends App {
  val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem")
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props[Subscriber], name="Subscriber")
}
```

#### `Publisher.scala`

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.cluster.pubsub.{DistributedPubSub, DistributedPubSubMediator}
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

class Publisher extends Actor {
  import DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish
  // activate the extension
  val mediator = DistributedPubSub(context.system).mediator

  def receive = {
    case in: String => {
      val out = in.toUpperCase
      println(s"Received '$in', transformed to '$out'.")
      mediator ! Publish("content", out)
    }
  }
}

object PublisherMain extends App {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val system = ActorSystem("ClusterSystem", config.getConfig("PublishApp"))
  val actor = system.actorOf(Props[Publisher], name="Publisher")
  actor ! "something small"
}
```

#### `application.conf`

```
akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 2551
    }
  }

  cluster {
    seed-nodes = [
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2551",
      "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"]

    auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
  }
  log-dead-letters = 0
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
}

PublishApp {
  akka {
    loglevel = "DEBUG"
    actor {
      provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
    }
    remote {
      enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 2552
      }
      log-sent-messages = on
      log-received-messages = on
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm finding is that when I run the publisher's main, it will hang when attempting to publish to the "content" topic and the subscriber does not receive the message.

The publisher's logs contain the following:

> `[INFO] [12/09/2016 15:14:35.513] [ClusterSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-18] [akka://ClusterSystem/system/distributedPubSubMediator] Message [java.lang.String] from Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/user/Publisher#-1478463431] to Actor[akka://ClusterSystem/system/distributedPubSubMediator#-1539813703] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.`

I have been poring over the docs, but it seems like the topic concept is mentioned as more of an afterthought.

Why doesn't my subscriber receive this message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the publisher and the subscriber are actually fine. The problem comes from the fact that you started from the Distributed Pub Sub example. What you need as a precondition is of course the setup of the Cluster so that the messages are distributed through it.

`Main.scala`:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.cluster.Cluster
import com.example.Publisher
import com.example.Subscriber

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val systemName = "PubSub"
    val system1 = ActorSystem(systemName)
    val joinAddress = Cluster(system1).selfAddress
    Cluster(system1).join(joinAddress)
    val publisher = system1.actorOf(Props[Publisher], "publisher")

    Thread.sleep(5000)
    val system2 = ActorSystem(systemName)
    Cluster(system2).join(joinAddress)
    system2.actorOf(Props[Subscriber], "subscriber")

    Thread.sleep(5000)
    publisher ! "something"
  }
}
```

---

If you now run `Main.scala` you will see the following:

- system1 is being created and it joins the cluster (creating it implicitly)
- system2 is being created and it joins the cluster
- a message is sent to the publisher which then forwards it to the mediator, which then distributes it in the cluster
- the subscriber gets the message

---

**Edit:** I simplified your `application.conf` to look like this:

```
akka {
  loglevel = "INFO"
  actor {
    provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    log-remote-lifecycle-events = off
    netty.tcp {
      hostname = "127.0.0.1"
      port = 0
    }
  }

  log-dead-letters = 0
  log-dead-letters-during-shutdown = off
}
```

Note the `netty.tcp.port = 0` - this will guarantee that you get random ports assigned and there would be no port collision for members of the cluster. You can see in my output the ports 49759 and 49772

---

Output:

```
Running Main 
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.175] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.439] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759]
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.451] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Starting up...
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.537] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Started up successfully
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.537] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Registered cluster JMX MBean [akka:type=Cluster]
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.546] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Metrics will be retreived from MBeans, and may be incorrect on some platforms. To increase metric accuracy add the 'sigar.jar' to the classpath and the appropriate platform-specific native libary to 'java.library.path'. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.549] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Metrics collection has started successfully
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.573] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - No seed-nodes configured, manual cluster join required
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.594] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] is JOINING, roles []
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:09.606] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] to [Up]
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.598] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Starting remoting
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.616] [main] [akka.remote.Remoting] Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772]
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.617] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772] - Starting up...
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.626] [main] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772] - Started up successfully
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.627] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772] - Metrics will be retreived from MBeans, and may be incorrect on some platforms. To increase metric accuracy add the 'sigar.jar' to the classpath and the appropriate platform-specific native libary to 'java.library.path'. Reason: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hyperic.sigar.Sigar
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.627] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772] - Metrics collection has started successfully
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.633] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772] - No seed-nodes configured, manual cluster join required
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.653] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772/user/subscriber] subscribing
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.844] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772] is JOINING, roles []
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:14.920] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772] - Welcome from [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759]
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:15.580] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-17] [akka.cluster.Cluster(akka://PubSub)] Cluster Node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49759] - Leader is moving node [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772] to [Up]
Received 'something', transformed to 'SOMETHING'.
[INFO] [12/10/2016 12:44:19.673] [PubSub-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.tcp://PubSub@127.0.0.1:49772/user/subscriber] Got SOMETHING
```

Comment: Interesting. If I have an arbitrary number of topics, will the _single_ cluster route the traffic accordingly, or will I need `n` cluster objects for `n` topics?

Comment: You can have multiple subscribers to one topic. With topics you also have the option to define topic groups. Actors may be subscribed to a named topic with a group id. If subscribing with a group id, each message published to a topic with the `sendOneMessageToEachGroup` flag set to `true` is delivered to one actor within each subscribing group.